# How to create a type-safe object that allows querying by any string

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, type-safety, typescript-types

I'd like to create an object + getter function, which would return either the known value type (if the key `extends keyof typeof obj`) or value type OR undefined if we don't know whether the key is in the object or not. Somehow like this:

```
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}

const a = obj.a
// typeof a = number

const b = obj['b']
// typeof b = number

let key: string = 'anything'
const d = obj[key]
// typeof d = number | undefined
if (d) {
  // typeof d = number
} else {
  // typeof d = undefined
}
```

When in reality what happens is

```
let key: string = 'anything'
const d = obj[key]
// TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ a: number; b: number; c: number; }'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ a: number; b: number; c: number; }'.

I've been trying to create a `get` function which would work this way, but can't get it to work. The result type is always either `any` or `unknown`.
```

Comment: How could we not know whether the key exists in a constant object?

Answer (score 1):

Did I get you right?

```js
const obj: Record<string, any> = { ... };

const getter = (key: string): string => {
    if (key in obj) return typeof obj[key];
    return undefined;
}
```

Comment: This does not work with `--strictNullChecks`, see [here](https://tsplay.dev/w18k8W).  Without `--strictNullChecks` there is no `undefined` type to worry about, but then the question would not have asked for the type `number | undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is a bit unsatisfactory with this sort of thing, in my opinion.  However, I think the usual way of doing this is to write a type guard.  Something like what's below.  isObjKey explicitly checks the actual JavaScript object contains the key (`obj[key] !== undefined`) AND tells TypeScript the type if the function returns true (`key is keyof typeof obj`).  Now if we test using it TypeScript knows it has a number in the first branch of the 'if' when you do obj[key], which I think is what you are asking for.  The unsatisfactoriness arises in that we've had to write a new and difficult function to do something trivial AND we've retrieved obj[key] twice, just to get type safety on a constant object.

```
const obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
};

let key: string = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'a' : 'anything';

function isObjKey(key: string): key is keyof typeof obj {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(key);
}

if (isObjKey(key)) {
    const d = obj[key];
    // d is a number here as far as TypeScript is concerned
    console.log(d);
}
else {
    // key isn't a valid key of obj, there's no need for another obj[key] access
    // (but if you do it's type any, not undefined)
    console.log('undefined');
}
```

An alternative is just to hack it.  You assert to TypeScript that your key is definitely a key of obj, even though it may not be, and TypeScript thinks it has a number after obj[key]:

```
const d = obj[key as keyof typeof obj];
if (d) {
    // TypeScript thinks d is a number
    console.log(d);
} else {
    // TypeScript still thinks d is a number, but it probably doesn't matter!
    console.log('undefined');
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how it is unsatisfactory, since in your example key is absolutely potentially not a key of the obj. Checking it is what any good code should do. What should it do if "anything" was the key? It isn't a key

Comment: Thanks! I almost got it with your first example. Now the problem is that in addition to the actual type of the value, typescript says that it can be `undefined`. I get that in reality the object might have changed during runtime, but is there a way to tell TS that it can't be `undefined`? (If defined with `Object.freeze` we know that it cannot change)
[Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WGnXVm)

Comment: Firstly I've realized that my answer doesn't work if noImplicitAny is turned on, and I have edited it to fix that.  I've replaced `obj[key] !=== undefined` with `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)`

Comment: I don't think that's your problem though?  However, I don't understand what your problem is: are you saying  d is showing as 'number | undefined' in the 'if' statement (where I've written 'd is a number here')?  Because that's not what I'm seeing.  Where exactly is the issue (and with which variable?)?